# Where is the path for the downloaded Google document in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api-client

I'm trying to download the google document file with Ruby. I can't find the path for the downloaded file. I commanded with 'export_file' method in ruby like following:

**file_id = 'xxxxxx'
content =  google_drive.export_file(file_id,
                                    'application/pdf',
                                    download_dest: StringIO.new)**

The response is as below in the console.

Writing chunk (1389 bytes)
Writing chunk (1389 bytes)
Writing chunk (1389 bytes)
Writing chunk (1389 bytes)
Writing chunk (896 bytes)
Writing chunk (2 bytes)
Writing chunk (1234 bytes)
Success - #

=> #

Seems like something was downloaded but in the rails, I can't find the path for the downloaded file. I tried to search the file with the name ( the name I can see in the Google document) in vain.

How can I access the downloaded file? How can I access "content"? Please share your insight with me!

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will just add string to the StringIo object you need to write it to file after it is done

```
stringObj = StringIO.new

file_id = 'xxxxxx' content = google_drive.export_file(file_id, 'application/pdf', download_dest: stringObj )


File.open('detination.txt', 'w') do |f|
  f.puts(stringObj.read)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea! I don't know why but the file (destination.txt) size is 4kb and has nothing inside. When I do puts "#{stringObj}", the console prints #<StringIO:0x007ff3ced9be98>. Would you help me on this?

Comment: your file seems to be a pdf change it to destination.pdf, also which gem you are using ?

Comment: get file is a better option 

google_drive.get_file(file.id, download_dest: 'my_file.pdf')

Comment: file_id = 'xxx'

    obj = StringIO.new
    content = GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT.export_file(file_id,
                                    'application/pdf',
                                    download_dest: StringIO.new)
    File.open('detination.pdf', 'w') do |f|
      f.puts(obj.read)
    end

Comment: When I commanded get_file(file_id, download_dest: "test.pdf"), the console error is Google::Apis::ClientError: Invalid request .

Comment: GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT.export_file(file_id, 'application/pdf', download_dest: "test.pdf")

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the answer above did not work. I'm using `google-api-client ~> 0.28.4` and `Rails 5.2.2`.
And I just wanted to download Google Spreadsheets using Drive API. I have a service to authenticate and a service to access the drive account using a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount).

This is the service method that downloads the file in my rails server to a local file:

```
def download_file(file_id)
  content = service.export_file(
    file_id,
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    download_dest: "tmp/#{file_id}.xlsx"
  )
end
```

Then in the controller reads that file and passes down the file to the client in the response like this:

```
def download_file
  file_id = params[:file_id] || ''

  drive_service = GoogleApisService::Drive.new
  file_name = drive_service.download_file(file_id)

  send_file "tmp/#{file_id}.xlsx", type: "application/xlsx", filename: "#{file_id}.xlsx", disposition: 'inline'
end
```

That's the way I save the downloaded file from Google Drive to a *temp file* and then it is served into the response.